# Simple loop in R to produce multiple tables

Tags: r

I want to produce tables from a list of column names, not sure why neither of the commands below don't produce output:

```
    mytable <- function(x) {
     table(to_label(x))
    }

    mylist <- c("d$col1", "d$col2")

    lapply(mylist, FUN = mytable)

    for (i in mylist) {
      mytable(i)
    }
```

Comment: 1) Where is `to_label` defined? In a package? 2) `"d$col1"` and `"d$col2"` are just character strings, not vectors. 3) Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(d[, c("col1", "col2")])`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(d[, c("col1", "col2")], 20))`.

Comment: mylist = c("col1", "col2"); for (i in mylist) print(mytable(d[[i]]))